# Validate the float value range in karate framework

Tags: decimal, karate

My scenario is to check whether a field accepts range from 0.01 to 25000 .. it can be decimal value . What is way to do it in karate framework.. I used below regex which is not correct

## regex [.0-9]*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just multiply by 1 to convert a string to a number

```
* def foo = '0.2'
* assert (foo * 1) < 0.3
```

Also please read: https://github.com/intuit/karate#type-conversion